# how to use wildcard in cmake install

Tags: cmake, installation, wildcard

I can install one specific file. When using wildcard in the same command, it complain the file does not exist.

### This is the one that works

```
install(FILES  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libproduction_rdict.pcm DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

### This is the one not working

```
install(FILES  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*_rdict.pcm DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

The error message is:

```
-- Install configuration: ""
CMake Error at Source/cmake_install.cmake:49 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "/home/wxie/AI/CUDA/cuda_exmaple/example_2/Build/Source/*_rdict.pcm".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
```

Answer (score 12):

Command flow `install(FILES)` requires all files to be listed explicitly.

For install several files by pattern, use `install(DIRECTORY)` and its *PATTERN* option:

```
install(DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*_rdict.pcm")
```

More information about `install(DIRECTORY)` and patterns can be found in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html#installing-directories).

Comment: The install(DIRECTORY) put the *.pcm file in the "lib/Build/" directory, while the actual lib file is in "lib" directory. For my purpose, I need the lib file and the pcm file in the same directory. Is there an option to do it? IOne solution is to loop over the file list and install one by one. Would be nice to have a simpler solution

Comment: With proper *DIRECTORY* and *DESTINATION* options you may adjust proper installation path of the file. Or do you mean that in this case installing the directory will erase files installed by other ways (e.g. with `install(TARGET)`)? "One solution is to loop over the file list and install one by one." - You may collect files using GLOB and pass resulted list into `install(FILES)` command.

Comment: almost working but still not perfect. The symptom is as follows:

"cmake ../;
make;
make install"

then I got the message: 
   "Install the project...;
-- Install configuration: ""
but the file is not installed. Then I need to do it again :

    "cmake ../;
    make install "

This time it works.  Why does it need to execute twice "cmake ../" to have it done?

Comment: this is what I did

"file(GLOB_RECURSE PCM_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Source/*.pcm); 
"install(FILES  ${PCM_FILES} DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})"
I think  the reason is cmake can not find the pcm file before "make" because it does not exist until "make" is done. When do it a 2nd time, the pcm file is there and and this time it works.

Comment: "I think the reason is cmake can not find the pcm file before "make" because it does not exist until "make" is done." - Exactly. `FILE(GLOB)` searches files immediately.

Comment: Any solution to bypass that?

Comment: I still don't understand why `install(DIRECTORY)` is not working for you. Could you provide **absolute paths** to which the variables `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH` refer, the **absolute path** with the file in the build tree, and desited **absolute install path** for that file?

Comment: It's working. It's just I have to execute twice "cmake ../" which is a bit annoying. Another solution is to "add_custom_target", which seems to be the most convenient solution for me. I will go for that. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Wait, so you need to run `cmake` twice in case of `install(DIRECTORY)`? From the previous comments I understand that it was needed for `file(GLOB)`.

Comment: With the DESTINATION property set to './', the DLLs do end up in the top level directory with the executable file : install(DIRECTORY ${COMPILER_PROGRAM_DIRECTORY}
        DESTINATION .
        FILES_MATCHING
            PATTERN "libgcc*.dll"
            PATTERN "libstdc++*.dll"
            PATTERN "libwinpthread*.dll"
        )

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is what I end up doing:

```
add_custom_target(move_pcmfile
COMMAND mv ${BUILD_DIR}/Source/*.pcm  ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

After "make", I just do "make move_pcmfile". This seems to be the most convenient way of solving my problem.

Comment: `mv`?! That sounds like you're going to destroy your build tree...